# How does one programmatically determine the default/main branch in a GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, github-api

I have a shell script that runs over a Git repository, and it compares the current branch to the default branch.

Right now it's hard-coded to `master`, but I need it to be dynamic to whatever the default/main branch of the repo is.

Is there a command to get the default branch of a repo, **without using the GitHub API**?

Comment: There is no "default" branch. (The default *name* of the initial branch is "master", though.)

Comment: default in the sense, that when you make a PR it's the default branch that it's made against. I'm aware that that's a github/gitlab concept, I'm trying to figure out if there's anything that denotes a branch as being the "main" one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-api%5D+default+branch

Comment: the closest answer I could find is here, and doesn't require the API https://stackoverflow.com/a/64795507/3121906

Comment: That's not reliable, however: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666357/git-how-to-get-default-branch#comment95550167_44750379

Comment: Why without using the GitHub API?